Need an Oracle sql script to list database users which have more than read only access on tables in database
Need an Oracle sql script to list database users which have more than read only access on tables in database.
To identify database users that have more than read access on database tables. Access such as Insert, delete, update etc besides READ/SELECT.

Hi - you haven't actually asked a question. As this isn't a free code writing service, please update your question with what you've managed to write so far and explain the issue that you're facing

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
